# Begining Java calling an integer to another method (I think)

Tags: java

> Write an application that reads 5 numbers between 1 and 30 For each number that reads, your program will display the same number of adjacent asterisks. For example, if your program reads the number 7, it will display *******. Display the bars of asterisk after you read all 5 numbers.

So far I have this:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class AsteriskGenerator { 
    public static void main(String[] args){ 

        AsteriskGenerator asteriskGenerator = new AsteriskGenerator();    

        int nb1 = 0; 
        int nb2 = 0; 
        int nb3 = 0; 
        int nb4 = 0; 
        int nb5 = 0;

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in); 
        System.out.print("Please, Enter a number between 1 - 30 "); 
        nb1 = input.nextInt(); 

        System.out.print("Please, Enter a number between 1 - 30 "); 
        nb2 = input.nextInt(); 

        System.out.print("Please, Enter a number between 1 - 30 "); 
        nb3 = input.nextInt(); 

        System.out.print("Please, Enter a number between 1 - 30 "); 
        nb4 = input.nextInt(); 

        System.out.print("Please, Enter a number between 1 - 30 "); 
        nb5 = input.nextInt(); 
    } 
    void asteriskGenerator(int[] nb1) { 
        for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++){ 
            System.out.print("*"); 
            System.out.println(); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

What should I do next? thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of errors in the code.This works check it.
 Instead of using 5 different variables i have used an array of size 5 to   take input.

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    System.out.print("Please, Enter a number between 1 - 30 "); 
    nb[i]=input.nextInt();
}
```

As you need to print the **nb[i]** number of asterisks where **nb[i]** is ith number in the array so you need to **iteratate nb[i] times for each nb[i] in the array**

In simple words extracting each nb[i] of the array and iterate nb[i] times

```
for(int i = 0; i <nb.length; i++)//iterarting over the array to get nb[i]
{
    for(int j=1;j<=nb[i];j++)//iterating nb[i] times where nb[i] is the ith element of the array
    {
        System.out.print("*"); 
    }
    System.out.println(); 
}
```

Here is full working code.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class AsteriskGenerator { 
    public static void main(String[] args){ 

    AsteriskGenerator asteriskGenerator = new AsteriskGenerator(); 

    int nb[]=new int[5];
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in); 
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        System.out.print("Please, Enter a number between 1 - 30 "); 
        nb[i]=input.nextInt();
    }
    input.close();


    asteriskGenerator.asteriskGenerator(nb);
    } 
    void asteriskGenerator(int nb[])
    { 
        for(int i = 0; i <  nb.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j=1;j<=nb[i];j++)
            {
                System.out.print("*"); 
            }
            System.out.println(); 
        } 
    } 

}
```

Hope it helps.Happy Coding!!

Comment: Thanks a million, this worked. I'm hoping to reverse engineer this and understand it better.

Comment: You can ask if you have any doubt anytime

Answer (score 0):

I would rather do something like that:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class AsteriskGenerator{ 

    public static void main(String[] args){ 

        AsteriskGenerator asteriskGenerator = new AsteriskGenerator();         
        int[] nbrs = new int[4]; 

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in); 
        System.out.print("Please, Enter a number between 1 - 30 "); 
        nbrs[0] = input.nextInt(); 

        System.out.print("Please, Enter a number between 1 - 30 "); 
        nbrs[1] = input.nextInt(); 

        System.out.print("Please, Enter a number between 1 - 30 "); 
        nbrs[2] = input.nextInt(); 

        System.out.print("Please, Enter a number between 1 - 30 "); 
        nbrs[3] = input.nextInt(); 

        System.out.print("Please, Enter a number between 1 - 30 "); 
        nbrs[4] = input.nextInt(); 

        for(int nb : nbrs){

            asteriskGenerator(nb);  
        }
    } 

    void asteriskGenerator(int nb1){ 

        for(int i = 0; i < nb1; i++){

            System.out.print("*"); 
            System.out.println(); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Didn't test but it's should work. And try to read what you are doing at least, it's wasn't have sense....

Comment: thanks, it all looks fine except one error, line 26 creates the error. "non-static method asteriskGenerator(int) cannot be referenced from a static context.

Comment: Do you use POO or not? Cause this code is kind of ugly, but you could just try replace void asteriskGenerator(int nb1) by public static void asteriskGenerator(int nb1)